# Problems with liquibase when starting the Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I have a `Spring Boot` application with `liquibase`, the first time I had no problems creating the tables but when I start it again I am having a problem that I cannot solve.

This is the **error**:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-03-21 12:22:27.294 ERROR 8828 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.time.LocalDateTime and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1153) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.dulcesproyect.server.DulcesServerApplication.main(DulcesServerApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.time.LocalDateTime and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.getRanChangeSets(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:328) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.AbstractChangeLogHistoryService.upgradeChecksums(AbstractChangeLogHistoryService.java:66) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.upgradeChecksums(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:297) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.checkLiquibaseTables(Liquibase.java:1174) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:178) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:368) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:316) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

I have tried the following but have not been able to solve the problem:

-> Empty databasechangelog and databasechangeloglock tables

-> Change mysql version in `pom`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.22</version>
</dependency>
```

-> `mvn clean`

But nothing I've tried has fixed the problem. How can I solve this to start the application without problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with Spring-Boot 2.4.3. Check it out: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1639

You can either use Spring-Boot 2.4.2 (that's what I did) or you can update Liquibase to version 4.3.1.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is the last version that appears to me of liquibase: ``<liquibase.version>3.10.3</liquibase.version>``, How can I update to that version?

Comment: Just add it as dependency, as you tried with MySQL connector. I’ve updated my answer

Comment: The updated dependency will likely be part of spring boot from version 2.5 as of this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25330).