# exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: liquibase/Scope

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase, multi-module

**I have multimodule project using Spring Boot and liquibase. If i run it usring mvn spring-boot:run it works, but if i run it using intellej i get this error:**

```
2022-07-15 14:22:36 ERROR 6908 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]: Factory method 'liquibase' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: liquibase/Scope
    at spring.beans@5.3.20/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at spring.beans@5.3.20/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at spring.beans@5.3.20/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at spring.beans@5.3.20/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at spring.beans@5.3.20/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at spring.beans@5.3.20/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at spring.beans@5.3.20/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at spring.beans@5.3.20/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at spring.beans@5.3.20/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at spring.beans@5.3.20/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at spring.beans@5.3.20/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at spring.beans@5.3.20/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at spring.context@5.3.20/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at spring.context@5.3.20/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at spring.context@5.3.20/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at spring.boot@2.7.0/org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66)
    at spring.boot@2.7.0/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at spring.boot@2.7.0/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at spring.boot@2.7.0/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at spring.boot@2.7.0/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at spring.boot@2.7.0/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at package/module1.Application.main(Application.java:23)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]: Factory method 'liquibase' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: liquibase/Scope
    at spring.beans@5.3.20/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at spring.beans@5.3.20/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: liquibase/Scope
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.<init>(SpringLiquibase.java:56)
    at spring.boot.autoconfigure@2.7.0/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.<init>(DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.java:36)
    at spring.boot.autoconfigure@2.7.0/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.createSpringLiquibase(LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java:113)
    at spring.boot.autoconfigure@2.7.0/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.liquibase(LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java:90)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at spring.beans@5.3.20/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: liquibase.Scope
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 29 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Module info of my module:

```
open module module1 {
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.cloud.commons;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires lombok;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.core;
    requires org.slf4j;
    requires spring.data.jpa;
    requires org.apache.logging.slf4j;
    requires spring.web;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation;
    requires spring.cloud.openfeign.core;
    requires org.bouncycastle.provider;
    requires org.apache.commons.codec;
    requires io.netty.handler;
    requires java.transaction;
    requires spring.beans;;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it? I will aprecciate it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? What version of Liquibase are you using?  This previous StackOverflow question may help guide you in the right direction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66731773/problems-with-liquibase-when-starting-the-spring-boot-application

Comment: It does not help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your Liquibase files are in a folder named `liquibase`. Rename it to something else like `liquibase-migration-files` or equivalent, but definitely different from just `liquibase`.

My interpretation is that having a `liquibase` folder make the ClassLoader think the package `liquibase` is declared in the module where your Liquibase configuration is stored, thus the ClassLoader doesn't try to look in the unnamed module where the Liquibase library is located.